# How do I use a variable instead of a string in the Pattern class?

Tags: java, regex

I am attempting to search for a word in between two words and am using the Pattern class in Java. So far my code is:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=PlaintiffAtty_0).*?(?=</span>)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sourcecode.toString());

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group().toString());
```

The first pattern word "PlaintiffAtty_0" will be changing as the number will increase, so I would like to use it as a variable. How would insert a variable there instead of having to change the string every time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use string concatenation and [`Pattern.quote`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29) to ensure that any special characters inside the string are treated literally:

```
Pattern.compile("(?<="+Pattern.quote(myString)+").*?(?=</span>)");
```

where `myString` is a variable, a method call, an access to an array, etc.

Comment: Just [`Pattern.quote`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String)) the input `String`. Magic.

Comment: @BoristheSpider You're right, I thought that `Pattern.quote` was a fancy name for `"\\Q"+str+"\\E"`, [but that's not entirely true](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/regex/Pattern.java). I deleted my answer, and edited this one with your suggestion. Thanks!